# Use namespace alias in subsequent Imports?

Tags: vb.net, namespaces, alias

I have a huge library with lots of namespaces and classes, nested to >10 levels deep. In most projects I will be using only one of the most nested namespaces at a time, so there is some kind of *root*, above which I will not `Import`. For example, the object I need lies within:

```
Imports MyObject = ns1.ns2.ns3.ns4.ns5.MyObject
```

And another one in:

```
Imports MyOtherObject = ns1.ns2.ns3.ns4.ns5.ns6.MyOtherObject
```

Problem is that `ns1` and other `nsX` can be very long name, so the whole lines goes way off screen and it's hard to follow. I was hoping you could declare an *alias* like this:

```
Imports MyRoot = ns1.ns2.ns3.ns4.ns5
```

And then use the above:

```
Imports MyObject = MyRoot.MyObject
Imports MyOtherObject = MyRoot.ns6.MyOtherObject
```

But it does not work like this, i.e. `Imports` do not see each other.

I tried using project-wide settings - same behavior. Is there a solution or a workaround?

I was thinking maybe it's possible to package namespaces into another namespace? (similar to how `My` works, but I could not find any good source on how to implement this)